# WPF Updating item from listbox mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I have a listbox that im binding items to. I allow the user to add/remove a text file and attach it to the object. When this happens, i want the item to update.

I never see this update take place. Ive attempted to use a ConotentControl and manipulate it through the style as well as the ContentTemplateSelector with no success. I obviously have a peice of my binding incorrect but i cant pinpoint where it is.

I can see that the value is indeed updated through the Live Property Explorer.

```
public enum FileState{None,Valid,Invalid};
public class AppPathLoc:ViewModelBase
{

    #region FileState
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="FileState" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    private const string FileStatePropertyName = "FileState";

    private FileState _fileState = FileState.None;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the FileState property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public FileState FileState
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileState;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_fileState == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _fileState = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(FileStatePropertyName);
        }
    }
    #endregion


    private string _filename = string.Empty;

    [Localizable(false)]
    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return _filename;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_filename != value)
            {
                _filename = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
            }
        }
    }

}



 public class ApplicationsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IDataService _dataService;


    #region · Properties ·


    #region SelectedAppPathLocation
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="SelectedAppPathLocation" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    private const string SelectedAppPathLocationPropertyName = "SelectedAppPathLocation";

    private AppPathLoc _selectedAppPathLocation = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the SelectedAppPathLocation property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public AppPathLoc SelectedAppPathLocation
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedAppPathLocation;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedAppPathLocation == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedAppPathLocation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(SelectedAppPathLocationPropertyName);
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region SelectedController
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="SelectedController" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    private const string SelectedControllerPropertyName = "SelectedController";

    private Controller _selectedController = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the SelectedController property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public Controller SelectedController
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedController;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedController == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedController = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(SelectedControllerPropertyName);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public ObservableCollection<string> LocationNames { get; set; }= new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<Controller> Controllers { get; set; }= new ObservableCollection<Controller>();
    public ObservableCollection<CApplication> Applications { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CApplication>();
    public ObservableCollection<AppPath> AppPaths { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<AppPath>();

    public ObservableCollection<AppPathLoc> AppPathLocs { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<AppPathLoc>();
    #endregion


    #region · Commands ·


    #region · RemoveTextCommand ·
    private RelayCommand<AppPathLoc> _removeTextCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the RemoveTextCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<AppPathLoc> RemoveTextCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _removeTextCommand
                ?? (_removeTextCommand = new RelayCommand<AppPathLoc>(ExecuteRemoveTextCommand));
        }
    }

    private async void ExecuteRemoveTextCommand(AppPathLoc appPathLoc)
    {
        var msgText = $"Removed TextBlock file {appPathLoc.FileName} for {appPathLoc.Location.LocName}";
        var name = appPathLoc.FileName;
        appPathLoc.BFile = null;
        appPathLoc.FileName = null;
        appPathLoc.OnPropertyChanged("FileState");
        OnPropertyChanged("AppPathLocs");
        var result = await _dataService.SaveAppPathLocationAsync(appPathLoc);
        if (result != null)
        {



            var msg = new SnackbarMessage { Content = msgText  };


            Kuka.UI.WPF.ViewModel.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Send(msg);

            SelectedAppPathLocation.LoadFileName();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region · AddTextCommand ·
    private RelayCommand<AppPathLoc> _addTextCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the AddTextCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<AppPathLoc> AddTextCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _addTextCommand
                ?? (_addTextCommand = new RelayCommand<AppPathLoc>(ExecuteAddTextCommand));
        }
    }

    private async void ExecuteAddTextCommand(AppPathLoc appPathLoc)
    {
        if (appPathLoc == null)
            return;
        var dlg = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Filter = Constants.TEXT_FILE_FILTER,
            InitialDirectory = Constants.BLOCK_PATH + SelectedController.RobotVendor.RvName
        };

        if(appPathLoc.FileState==FileState.Valid)
            dlg.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(appPathLoc.BFile);

        if (dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            appPathLoc.DialogName = "";
            appPathLoc.BFile = dlg.FileName;
            appPathLoc.FileName = Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName);
            appPathLoc.LoadFileName();

            await DispatcherHelper.RunAsync(() =>
            {


                appPathLoc.OnPropertyChanged("FileState");
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAppPathLocation");
                OnPropertyChanged("AppPathLocs");
            });
            appPathLoc.LoadFileName();
            var result = await _dataService.SaveAppPathLocationAsync(appPathLoc);
            var msgText = $"Added TextBlock file {result.FileName} for {result.Location.LocName}";
            var msg = new SnackbarMessage { Content = msgText };



            Kuka.UI.WPF.ViewModel.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Send(msg);



            //                SelectedAppPathLoc.OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region · AddAppPathLocationCommand ·
    private RelayCommand<AppPath> _addAppPathLocationCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the AddAppPathLocationCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<AppPath> AddAppPathLocationCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _addAppPathLocationCommand
                ?? (_addAppPathLocationCommand = new RelayCommand<AppPath>(ExecuteAddAppPathLocationCommand));
        }
    }

    private  void ExecuteAddAppPathLocationCommand(AppPath appPath)
    {

    }
    #endregion


    #region · RemoveAppPathLocationCommand ·
    private RelayCommand<AppPathLoc> _removeAppPathLocationCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the RemoveAppPathLocationCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<AppPathLoc> RemoveAppPathLocationCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _removeAppPathLocationCommand
                ?? (_removeAppPathLocationCommand = new RelayCommand<AppPathLoc>(ExecuteRemoveAppPathLocationCommand));
        }
    }

    private  void ExecuteRemoveAppPathLocationCommand(AppPathLoc appPathLoc)
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region · GetTextBlockCommand ·
    private RelayCommand<AppPathLoc> _getTextBlockCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the GetTextBlockCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<AppPathLoc> GetTextBlockCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _getTextBlockCommand
                ?? (_getTextBlockCommand = new RelayCommand<AppPathLoc>(ExecuteGetTextBlockCommand));
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteGetTextBlockCommand(AppPathLoc appPathLoc)
    {

    }
    #endregion
    #region · ControllerChangedCommand ·

    private RelayCommand<Controller> _controllerChangedCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ControllerChangedCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<Controller> ControllerChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _controllerChangedCommand
                ?? (_controllerChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<Controller>(ExecuteControllerChangedCommand));
        }
    }

    private async void ExecuteControllerChangedCommand(Controller controller)
    {
        Applications.Clear();
        AppPaths.Clear();
        AppPathLocs.Clear();
        var applications =await _dataService.GetApplicationsAsync(controller.ContNum);
        if (applications != null)
        {
            Applications = new ObservableCollection<CApplication>(applications);
            OnPropertyChanged("Applications");

        }

    }
    #endregion


    #region · ApplicationChangedCommand ·
    private RelayCommand<CApplication> _applicationChangedCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ApplicationChangedCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<CApplication> ApplicationChangedCommand => _applicationChangedCommand
                                                                   ?? (_applicationChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<CApplication>(ExecuteApplicationChangedCommand));

    private async void ExecuteApplicationChangedCommand(CApplication application)
    {
        AppPaths.Clear();

        if (application == null)
            return;
        if (!IsInDesignModeStatic)

            AppPathLocs.Clear();
        var appPaths = await _dataService.GetAppPathsAsync(application.CAppNum);
        if (appPaths != null)
        {
            AppPaths = new ObservableCollection<AppPath>(appPaths);
            OnPropertyChanged("AppPaths");
        }

        var appPathLocs = await _dataService.GetAppPathLocationsAsync(application);
        if (appPathLocs != null)
        {

            AppPathLocs = new ObservableCollection<AppPathLoc>(appPathLocs);
            OnPropertyChanged("AppPathLocs");

            OnPropertyChanged("AppPathLocs");
        }

    }
    #endregion



    #region · AppPathsChangedCommand ·
    private RelayCommand<AppPath> _appPathsChangedCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the AppPathsChangedCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<AppPath> AppPathsChangedCommand => _appPathsChangedCommand
                                                           ?? (_appPathsChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<AppPath>(ExecuteAppPathsChangedCommand));

    private async void ExecuteAppPathsChangedCommand(AppPath appPath)
    {
        if(!IsInDesignModeStatic)
        AppPathLocs.Clear();
        if (appPath == null)
            return;
        var appPathLocs = await _dataService.GetAppPathLocationsAsync(appPath.AppPathID);
        if (appPathLocs != null)
        {
            AppPathLocs = new ObservableCollection<AppPathLoc>(appPathLocs);
            OnPropertyChanged("AppPathLocs");
        }


    }
    #endregion


    #endregion
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ApplicationsViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public ApplicationsViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        if(!(IsInDesignMode||IsInDesignModeStatic))
            GetData();
    }

    private async void GetData()
    {
        var locationNames = await _dataService.GetLocationNamesAsync().ContinueWith(r =>
        {
            return r.Result.GroupBy(o => o).Select(o => o.Key).ToList();
        });
        if (locationNames != null)
        {
            LocationNames=new ObservableCollection<string>(locationNames);
            OnPropertyChanged("LocationNames");
        }
        var controllers = await _dataService.GetControllersAsync();
        if (controllers != null)
        {
            Controllers = new ObservableCollection<Controller>(controllers);
            OnPropertyChanged("Controllers");
        }

        if (IsInDesignMode || IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {

            /*
            const int max = 15;
            var rnd = new Random();

            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("D:\\Temp", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Take(max);

            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {

                var num = rnd.Next(0,max);
                var apl = new AppPathLoc();
                apl.Location = new Location {LocName = $"Item {num}"};
                var file = files.ElementAt(num);
                apl.BFile = file;
                apl.FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                AppPathLocs.Add(apl);
            }

            var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {
                var idx = rnd.Next(0, max);
                var apl = AppPathLocs[idx];
                apl.BFile = apl.BFile == null ? files.ElementAt(idx) : null;
                apl.LoadFileName();

            };
            timer.IsEnabled = true;
            */
        }



    }


}
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid  Style="{StaticResource Grid}" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <wpf:ColorZone Padding="4 0" wpf:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth2" Mode="Light" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0 0 4 0"  >
        <Grid Margin="8">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboSelectorText}"/>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <!-- Controller -->
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Controllers}" 
                      x:Name="Controllers"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      SelectedIndex="0"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedController }"
                      wpf:HintAssist.Hint="Controllers"
                      wpf:HintAssist.IsFloating="True"

                      DisplayMemberPath="ContName"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ControllerChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}"  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=Controllers}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>

                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>


            <!-- Applications-->
            <ComboBox
                x:Name="Applications"
                SelectedIndex="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                wpf:HintAssist.Hint="Applications"
                wpf:HintAssist.IsFloating="True"

                ItemsSource="{Binding Applications}"
                DisplayMemberPath="AppType.AppTypeName"
                >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ApplicationChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}"  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=Applications}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>

                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>

            <!-- AppPaths-->
            <ComboBox
                x:Name="AppPaths"
                SelectedIndex="0"
                Grid.Column="2"
                wpf:HintAssist.Hint="AppPaths"
                wpf:HintAssist.IsFloating="True"

                ItemsSource="{Binding AppPaths}"
                DisplayMemberPath="StandardPath.PathName"
                >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding AppPathsChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}"  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=AppPaths}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>

                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>


        </Grid>

    </wpf:ColorZone>
    <wpf:ColorZone Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8" >
        <GroupBox Header="Locations">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AppPathLocs,IsAsync=True}" x:Name="AppPathLocations" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAppPathLocation}"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  >
                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dataLinqClasses:AppPathLoc}" >
                        <view:AppPathLocListItemView/>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListBox.Resources>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCardsListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4 0"/>




                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu  DataContext="{Binding Path=ApplicationsModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="Locations">

                            <MenuItem Header="Add Location"  Command="{Binding AddAppPathLocationCommand,Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource AddStyle}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Remove Location" Command="{Binding RemoveAppPathLocationCommand,Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedAppPathLocation}" Style="{StaticResource RemoveStyle}"/>
                        </MenuItem>


                        <MenuItem  Header="{x:Static simulationWorkflow:Constants.ADD_TEXT_BLOCK_HEADER}"   Command="{Binding AddTextCommand,Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedAppPathLocation}" Style="{DynamicResource AddStyle}" />
                        <MenuItem Header="{x:Static simulationWorkflow:Constants.REMOVE_TEXT_BLOCK_HEADER}" Command="{Binding RemoveTextCommand,Mode=OneWay}" Style="{DynamicResource RemoveStyle}"  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedAppPathLocation}"/>
                        <MenuItem  Header="{x:Static simulationWorkflow:Constants.OPEN_FILE_LOCATION}" Command="{x:Static commands:StaticCommands.OpenAppPathCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedAppPathLocation.BFile}"/>

                    </ContextMenu>

                </ListBox.ContextMenu>
            </ListBox>
        </GroupBox>


    </wpf:ColorZone>

    <Button Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Panel.ZIndex="999" Margin="16">
        <wpf:PackIcon Kind="Plus"/>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

**Item**

```
<Grid   Margin="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="AppPathGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Name : " Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0 0 4 0"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Location.LocName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource  TitleTextBox}"/>
    </Grid>
    <Expander Grid.Row="1">
         <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dataLinqClasses:AppPathLoc}">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="File : " Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=FileName}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="File "/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" is specified but doesn't exist!"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <wpf:PackIcon Kind="AlertCircle" Grid.Column="1">
                            <wpf:PackIcon.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </wpf:PackIcon.Triggers>
                        </wpf:PackIcon>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Expander.HeaderTemplate>

        <Expander.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Expander}}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FileState}" Value="{x:Static dataLinqClasses:FileState.Valid}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileState, IsAsync=True}" Value="Valid">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FileState}" Value="{x:Static dataLinqClasses:FileState.Invalid}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileState, IsAsync=True}" Value="Invalid">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FileState}" Value="{x:Static dataLinqClasses:FileState.None}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileState, IsAsync=True}" Value="None">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Expander.Style>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ApplicationsModel.GetTextBlockCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBox Style="{x:Null}" Text="{Binding TextBlock}" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                    <Button Content="Change File"/>
                    <Button Content="Save"/>
                    <Button Content="Close"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Expander>



</Grid>
```

All im trying to get to work right now is basically change the background color when the value of file state changes..

Comment: Sorry, So when the user attaches the file, all that takes place in the item is that the filename of the item is shown. I am updating the item, and changing the FileState Property, i am currently simply expecting to see the background color change depending on the state, but it doesnt happen. Ive dumbed it down to this because of the current problem im having. the original plan was to have a contentcontrol that would change the template depending on the FileState property.

Comment: And you're sure `FileState`'s setter is being called with a different value?Can we see the code that sets those two properties when the user selects a file?

Comment: Yes, I was concerned that maybe that wasnt happening but i confirmed it with the Live Property explorer

Comment: I don't know what the Live Property Explorer is. I need to see the code.

Comment: Im using Visual Studio 2015 which allows me to view the live values of the ui.

Comment: I'm using the comment feature in Stack Overflow to tell you that I need to see the code.

Comment: Updated and added

Comment: You never set the value of `FileState` anywhere in this code. You just call `appPathLoc.OnPropertyChanged("FileState");`, without changing the value. Is `LoadFileName()` supposed to do that?

Comment: Sorry ed, yes, LoadFileName does change the actual value of filestate depending on if the path is valid or not.

Comment: Well, you'll have to find somebody else to fight the eternal battle to see the code where you set `FileState`. You've defeated me. Congratulations.

Comment: I think im finally finding something, it looks like its a threading problem. I apologize that i didnt include the snippet for updating filestate. I kind of figured that you would be able to take me at my word for it when i said i know i was updating it.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was solved because Im using Linq2Sql, but in my partial class i was also implementing INotifyPropertyChanged twice